# Currency switcher

Tags: 8, commerce

Is there a currency negotiation service in Drupal Commerce 8?
How can I change product currency on my multi currencies e-commerce?

Answer (score 0):

Please check https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_currency_switcher which is currently in active development. You can use this to switch your currencies and  also set either exchange rates between your currencies or have your own price fields per currency for your product.

Comment: Initial commit 30 May 2017, last commit 17 Oct 2017 - just a week after you said it was in active development. Seems abandoned and not very useful at this point.